# Conical Cups Related Rates

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image: Conical Paper Cup]

My teacher provided the solution and I don't want to just copy it down.

I know we have V=$\frac{\pi r^2h}{3}$ and $dh/dt = 2$. 
What I don't understand is how V=$\frac{\pi r^2h}{3}$ becomes V=$\frac{\pi h^3}{3}$. If someone could explain that to me, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top $r=h=10$ cm. By using similar triangles, you have that $r=h$ at all heights. In general, you would need to write $r$ in terms of $h$, no matter the shape of the cone. In this case is trivial.